# Image Upload Django with Ckeditor Failed Undefined

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, web-development-server

I'm trying to create a blog page with Django. I'm using CKEditor to add text. When I upload images locally, I don't have any issues, but I encounter a problem when I deploy the project to the server. When I go to the image upload section in CKEditor and click "Send to Server," I receive an "undefined" error in the popup that appears.

[failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOT7T.jpg)

but I don't get this error when I start the project in my local.

Ckeditor -v = django-ckeditor==6.7.0
Django -v = Django==4.2.4

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_STORAGE_BACKEND = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
FILEBROWSER_REMOVE_DIALOG_TABS = 'image:Upload'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
   'default': {
        'filebrowserUploadUrl': '/ckeditor/upload/',
        'filebrowserBrowseUrl': '/ckeditor/browse/',
        'toolbar': 'Full',  # Toolbar ayarları düzeltildi
        'toolbar_Full': [
            ['Styles', 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'SpellChecker', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
            ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'],
            ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
            ['Smiley', 'SpecialChar'], ['Source'],
            ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],
            ['Indent', 'Outdent'],
            ['Maximize'],
            {'name': 'about', 'items': ['CodeSnippet']},
            {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
        ],
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'fillEmptyBlocks': False,
        'extraPlugins': 'justify,liststyle,indent,codesnippet,devtools,uploadimage',  # Resim eklentisi eklendi
        'uploadUrl': '/ckeditor/upload/',  # Resim yükleme URL'si eklendi
   },
}
```

Have you encountered this problem? I would like your comments on the topic. enjoy your work

I didn't expect to run into a problem here. It is interesting that it does not get an error in the local and not take it to the server.

Comment: Are there any errors in browser console?

Comment: no, i don't see any error in console either.
I gave up on ckeditor, switched to django-editor-js, and I'm having trouble uploading images there. You don't have a problem in my local, but when I go to the server, I have a problem

Comment: Hello,
I couldn't find the source of the problem, but I came up with a different solution. Here, I throw the related images to the Media folder in the main directory, then I take them from there and throw them to Bucket and delete them from the media folder.
This is how I did it for now :D